# How to fix segmentation fault in genrated llvm bytecode?

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm, llvm-ir

I'm currently working on a compiler using llvm, and it generates this code, which produces a segfault at the last dtore instruction of the case_body block of the test.main$v function. I'm not an expert in debugging manually in general and am especially a beginner with gdb etc.

If someone could point out what grave error I've made here I'd be very grateful!

```
; ModuleID = 'test.bc'
source_filename = "test"

%test.Node = type { i32, %test.OptionalNode }
%test.OptionalNode = type { i8, [8 x i8] }
%test.OptionalNode.nil = type { i8 }
%test.OptionalNode.some = type { i8, %test.Node* }

declare i32 @printf(i8*, ...)

define void @"test.Node.!ctor$[test.Node]i[test.OptionalNode]"(%test.Node* %this, i32 %_value, %test.OptionalNode %_next) {
entry:
  %arg0 = alloca %test.Node*
  store %test.Node* %this, %test.Node** %arg0
  %arg1 = alloca i32
  store i32 %_value, i32* %arg1
  %arg2 = alloca %test.OptionalNode
  store %test.OptionalNode %_next, %test.OptionalNode* %arg2
  %ldarg1 = load i32, i32* %arg1
  %tmpld_cls = load %test.Node*, %test.Node** %arg0
  %tmpfld = getelementptr inbounds %test.Node, %test.Node* %tmpld_cls, i32 0, i32 0
  store i32 %ldarg1, i32* %tmpfld
  %ldarg2 = load %test.OptionalNode, %test.OptionalNode* %arg2
  %tmpld_cls1 = load %test.Node*, %test.Node** %arg0
  %tmpfld2 = getelementptr inbounds %test.Node, %test.Node* %tmpld_cls1, i32 0, i32 1
  store %test.OptionalNode %ldarg2, %test.OptionalNode* %tmpfld2
  ret void
}

define i32 @"test.main$v"() {
entry:
  %n = alloca %test.OptionalNode
  %enm = alloca %test.OptionalNode
  %0 = bitcast %test.OptionalNode* %enm to %test.OptionalNode.nil*
  %1 = getelementptr inbounds %test.OptionalNode.nil, %test.OptionalNode.nil* %0, i32 0, i32 0
  store i8 0, i8* %1
  %2 = load %test.OptionalNode, %test.OptionalNode* %enm
  store %test.OptionalNode %2, %test.OptionalNode* %n
  %s = alloca %test.OptionalNode
  %enm1 = alloca %test.OptionalNode
  %3 = bitcast %test.OptionalNode* %enm1 to %test.OptionalNode.nil*
  %4 = getelementptr inbounds %test.OptionalNode.nil, %test.OptionalNode.nil* %3, i32 0, i32 0
  store i8 0, i8* %4
  %5 = load %test.OptionalNode, %test.OptionalNode* %enm1
  %tmpalloc = alloca %test.Node*
  %6 = load %test.Node*, %test.Node** %tmpalloc
  call void @"test.Node.!ctor$[test.Node]i[test.OptionalNode]"(%test.Node* %6, i32 3, %test.OptionalNode %5)
  %tmpload = load %test.Node*, %test.Node** %tmpalloc
  %enm2 = alloca %test.OptionalNode
  %7 = bitcast %test.OptionalNode* %enm2 to %test.OptionalNode.some*
  %8 = getelementptr inbounds %test.OptionalNode.some, %test.OptionalNode.some* %7, i32 0, i32 0
  store i8 1, i8* %8
  %9 = getelementptr inbounds %test.OptionalNode.some, %test.OptionalNode.some* %7, i32 0, i32 1
  store %test.Node* %tmpload, %test.Node** %9
  %10 = load %test.OptionalNode, %test.OptionalNode* %enm2
  store %test.OptionalNode %10, %test.OptionalNode* %s
  %r = alloca i32
  store i32 0, i32* %r
  br label %case_check

case_check:                                       ; preds = %entry
  %11 = getelementptr inbounds %test.OptionalNode, %test.OptionalNode* %s, i32 0, i32 0
  %12 = load i8, i8* %11
  %tmpicmpeq = icmp eq i8 %12, 1
  br i1 %tmpicmpeq, label %case_body, label %case_after

case_body:                                        ; preds = %case_check
  %n3 = alloca %test.Node*
  %13 = bitcast %test.OptionalNode* %s to %test.OptionalNode.some*
  %14 = getelementptr inbounds %test.OptionalNode.some, %test.OptionalNode.some* %13, i32 0, i32 1
  %15 = load %test.Node*, %test.Node** %14
  store %test.Node* %15, %test.Node** %n3
  %tmpld_cls = load %test.Node*, %test.Node** %n3
  %tmpgetfldgep = getelementptr inbounds %test.Node, %test.Node* %tmpld_cls, i32 0, i32 0
  %tmpgetfldld = load i32, i32* %tmpgetfldgep
  store i32 %tmpgetfldld, i32* %r
  br label %case_after

case_after:                                       ; preds = %case_body, %case_check
  br label %match_end

match_end:                                        ; preds = %case_after
  %tmploadlocal = load i32, i32* %r
  ret i32 %tmploadlocal
}

define i32 @main() {
entry:
  %call = tail call i32 @"test.main$v"()
  ret i32 %call
}
```

Comment: Try applying `debugify` pass on your IR to add debug information for it, and then debug the binary in `gdb` or `lldb`.

Comment: @arrowd i tried that but lli and llc only complained that they would ignore the debug information because of an invalid version (0) (I'm using llvm 6.0.1). btw I've narrowed it down to the store of the case_body block. So the segfault does not happen if i comment out that ir line

Comment: Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55328463/why-does-this-llvm-ir-code-produce-unexpected-results